# Mapping exactly two values to one value

Tags: number-theory, functions, modular-arithmetic

Is there a function that maps 2 values such that one value is x and another is x^-1 , where x^-1 is the modulo inverse of x, to same output?

f(x)=f(x^-1) mod n, where n is large prime,so what is f?

Comment: hint: can you do this without the "modulo" step? There is already a well-known function that maps two to one, can you use it?

Comment: Okay it will do without modulo

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Modulo or no modulo, $x+x^{-1}$ will do, as will any function of it.

Comment: @ivan I was thinking of $abs(ln x)$.

Comment: That will do as well. Many things will do.